# Asyncronously load large Bitmap into ImageView

Tags: android

This question worry me for the long time.

I have a resource `R.drawable.photo` = ~5 Megabytes 
And i have a code :

```
private Bitmap mPhoto;

public void loadAndShow() {
    // default options
    mPhoto = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.photo, options);
    ImageView photo = findViewById(R.id.photo);
    photo.setImageBitmap(mPhoto);
}
```

Each time that i try to show up my drawable it takes long time.

**What actually i'm asking?**

How to load big bitmap into view asynchronously, without loss of performance? 
Without any lags in UI?

> **Note :** please do not provide answers related to some third-party libraries(Picasso, UniversalImageLoader, etc.)

Comment: why don't you use photo.setImageResource()?

Comment: @Christian you're right, but actually question about Bitmaps - doesn't matter what the source i used for image(resource, drawable, etc.)

Comment: Is this 5MB in its saved state? You really need to reduce the size. It won't display properley on the majority of phones / tablets anyway.

Comment: Resize the image. Why are you even putting a 5mb image in an apk?

Comment: @Squonk this is bitmap for Android TV.

Comment: @PedroOliveira doesn't matter what the source i used for image(resource, drawable, etc.). I can load bitmap from URL, for ex.

Comment: What options are you using? Are you using inSampleSize? Density? Did you read the documentation?

Comment: @PedroOliveira definitely. Google recommends to resize image. But no information what to do if Picture size is the similar to Retina display (4K UHD)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to load the image in another thread, and to set it to the ImageView on the main thread, once it is loaded.

This code should do the trick:

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap>() {
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.photo, options);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.photo)).setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
```